# why ejabberd denies generating token?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ejabberd

my problem is when i trying to generate token respond is 404 not found.

***request url***: http://localhost:5280/oauth/authorization_token?response_type=token&client_id=Client1&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5280&scope=get_roster+sasl_auth

***respond url***: http://localhost:5280/?error=access_denied&state=

in ouath errors list i found that access_denied will be returned if "The resource owner or authorization server denied the request".

please help me to solve this issue...

Comment: Did you enable oauth HTTP handler in ejabberd config ?

Comment: yes.commands_admin_access: configure
    commands:
      - add_commands: user
    oauth_expire: 3600 
    oauth_access: all

Answer (score 0):

From your feedback, it seems you did not add a handler in `ejabberd_http` listener, as described in documentation: https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/oauth/#toc_3

You should make sure `ejabberd_oauth` is declared for that listener and mapped to the path you expect.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to make snapshot. this is piece of config file

Comment: I do not see the whole file but your configuration is obviously incorrect. request_handlers is not supposed to be at same level than commands, for example. If you follow carefully the doc I have been referring to, you should be able to have a working config file. Anyway, you problem is configuration: You put options in wrong places.

Comment: take a look, could you tell me what is problem?

Comment: I already told you: Incorrect config file / Pieces of config in the wrong place / level. And also, please do not post screen to such offensive site.